# Move a collection from one DB to another DB within the same MongoDB instance

Tags: mongodb

I have many collections in database A. I want to copy some of them to database B in the same `MongoDB`.

I tried to copy whole database using `db.copyDatabase('A', 'B')`, but it has more than `300 GB` data. It will take ages to copy and I just want to copy a few collections from database A to database B.

Does anyone know how can I do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try it using mongo shell. you can copy collection from one db to another db using `renameCollection`. the `renameCollection` can run from **admin** database so first need to switch to **admin db**.

so ca follow bellow steps in mongo shell:

**step-1:** run this comment `use admin`

**step-2:** run bellow comment

```
db.runCommand({renameCollection:"sourcedb.sourceCollection",to:"targetdb.tragetCollection"})
```

for example:

```
use admin
db.runCommand({renameCollection:"funnel.countries",to:"test.countries"})
```

copied `countries` *collection* from **funnel** db to **test** db.

In background MongoDB will create dump for source collection and restore the dump automatically to target db collection

Comment: It is working perfectly! Thank you so much . I thought renameCollection only works when you want to change the collection name!

Comment: Also, I wonder will it work if i put different collections in one query, or I only can move one collection at each time. I am going to try

Comment: This will move the collection, not a copy (as it is a rename)

Comment: It is a dump and restore.  I just renamed a 3GB collection to another DB. It took a few minutes.

Comment: Note: collection indices are not preserved with this operation! You may want to re-create them.

Comment: But does not work with sharded collections.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) to dump the collections:

```
mongodump  --db A --collection coll --out yourbackupdir
```

and then import the collections using [`mongorestore`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/):

```
mongorestore --db B --collection coll yourbackupdir/
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But in my case , I just want to move few collections because it is too much to dump whole database.

Comment: There is no need to store it to a file. Use STDOUT and STDIN: `mongodump --db=A --collection=coll --archive=- | mongorestore --nsFrom="A.coll " --nsTo="B.coll " --archive=-` Collections can be specified by wild-card characters.